# Search all Words in a Sentence against a Sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am writing a Jquery for a Combo box. Data in my Combo Box some thing like "Test One Example Data" and there are around 17 sentences in the combo. When User types some Sentence , they should see all the word in the Given sentence are highlight in the Combo box text and show only which have those entered text.

For this I am using $each Jquery function.
    Algorithm goes like this
                 1) Entered text is split in words and kept as arrays
                 2) Check each word in the Combo box and apply the regular expression to Bold and filter.

Now is the way to check using Reg Ex rather going with "$each" function.

Example Data : "Test Line Should One"
"Test Line Should Two"
"Test Line Should Three"
"Test Line Could One"
"Test Line Must One"
"Test Line Should Two"
"Test Word Should Three"

And user enters "Should Line", Combo box should have : Test Line Should Two and Test Line Should Two.

Please help me in identifying the reg expression rather than ".each", as in IE 8 that is getting stuck.

Comment: And what have you tried so far??

Comment: `string2.indexOf(string1) == -1`

Comment: You are right, I have used the same thing to match

Answer (score -1):

You need to use JQuery **Autocomplete**

Read the **[Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)** documentation for more information

### Example:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
});
```